# Cannot delete file on aws s3 bucket

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on Nodejs and Expressjs applications. I want to delete an image on Aws-s3 which I uploaded with multer-s3.

I have tried so many examples that I saw online but none of them worked. For instance :

```
aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: '*******************',
  accessKeyId: '*****************',
  region: 'eu-west-3',
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();


  s3.deleteObject({ Bucket: 'schubox', Key: rayon.img }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    else console.log(data);
  });
```

This code does not throw any errors but nothing is deleted on the S3 side.
where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Here the thing is that you need to use "**await**" and "**promise()**" to ensure that the object is deleted before ending the execution (wait until delete process completes).

Checkout below changes and try it:-

```
 const params = { Bucket: 'schubox', Key: rayon.img }

 await s3.deleteObject(params).promise()
 console.log("file deleted Successfully")
```